# Why does Postgres perform only sequential scan instead of index scan

Tags: postgresql

I am running some queries on my table in Postgres. My table consist of data from 2010 to 2020 around 1.000.000 rows. Whichever query I test, Postgres only performs sequential scan.

For example, my query looks like this:

```sql
select id13 
from timestamppsql 
where timestamp1 >='2010-01-01 00:05:00' 
  and timestamp1<='2010-01-02 00:05:00'
```

This query affects only 290 rows so it should use an index scan. I have used a lot of queries but every time Postgres performs only the sequential scan.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) - no screenshots please. Make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: I removed the link to a spam site from your question. If you want to provide the execution plan as a link, use https://explain.depesz.com/